# Negative margin inside a 0px (but not 0.1px) padding container

Tags: css, margin, padding

I'm experiencing an unexpected behaviour when an element with negative margin is put inside an element with `padding: 0`, unexpected because it doesn't happen if the padding is set to even a tiny `padding: 0.1px`, effectively rendering 0 pixels of padding.

I made a [codepen](https://codepen.io/FabioSpampinato/pen/PNmmad) to demonstrate the issue, use the buttons to change the padding.

I've tried it on Chrome.

Is it supposed to be working this way? And if so, why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. This behavior is called [collapsing margin](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Box_Model/Mastering_margin_collapsing). To quote MDN:

> If there is no border, padding, [...] to separate the margin-bottom of a block from the margin-bottom of its last child, then those margins collapse. The collapsed margin ends up outside the parent.

You switch this on/off with your padding, as minimal as it may be. Modern browsers do sub-pixel rendering since some time.

Comment: I understand, but it still looks buggy to me: if I set the padding to 0.01px instead it behaves like if it was 0px (while the computed value is in fact 0.01px). I guess the meaning of 'no padding' should translate to 'a padding of length 0', or am I missing something?

Comment: "it behaves like if it was 0px". Well, the combination of screens (non-retina especially) and humans is not really this good to detect noticeable differences of 1/100 pixel. Which brings me to another question: which behavior _exactly_ are you questioning? For me it was the negative margin that gets or gets not applied so that the following buttons move to the purple container.

Comment: Exactly, and my response to your answer was just: "margins are supposed to collapse in this particular case if there's no padding, then why are they also collapsing if the padding is set to 0.01px which is still greater than 0?"

Comment: OK, interesting. In both Chrome and Firefox I do get different results for padding:0 and padding:0.01px, just as one would expect. Basically, padding:0.01px looks identical to padding:10px for me, margin-wise.

Comment: I've done a little more tests, for me it collapses on webkit browsers with a value of 0.01px (both with 'retina' mode enabled or not), it doesn't on the others that I tested (FF, IE, Edge) but using 0.001px instead is enough to have the margin collapsed everywhere. Guess we have to live with it.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="actions">
  <button onclick="set_padding ( 10 )">10px padding</button>
  <button onclick="set_padding ( 0,1 )">0.1px padding</button>
  <button onclick="set_padding ( 0 )">0 padding</button>
</div>
```

I put 0,1 in stade of 0.1 and it worked

Comment: Of course it did, commas are using to separate things, you are effectively passing 2 values to the functions, and the first one of them is 0, basically you are removing the passing.

Comment: oh yes, i just started learn that is me im wrong thanks and sorry